# Issues with Post 2 Post Plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, customization, themes

I am trying to create connections between some of my posts. I have pairs of posts that need to go together (post with a quiz). I found the [Post 2 Post](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts/) plugin, which seems perfect for what I need. I have installed the plugin, but whenever I add the following code to my theme's functions.php file I get a white screen whenever I try to save a page on the admin side (it still saves, but I get a white screen).

```
<?php
function my_connection_types() {
  p2p_register_connection_type( array(
    'name' => 'posts_to_quiz',
    'from' => 'post',
    'to' => 'quiz'
  ) );
}
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'my_connection_types', 100 );
?>
```

I switched themes and it corrects itself, so I know it is an issue with the theme, but not sure where to start debugging. I am using the [Bones framework](http://themble.com/bones/), but have made some changes (not much to the functions.php file though). Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you access to the webservers log so you can see the error message? or just activate visible error messages in wordpress, or just add ` error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   ini_set('display_errors','On');
   restore_error_handler();` ontop of your function.php to make error visible

Comment: These are the errors I see: http://cl.ly/image/3p0h2y2z2X2V. Any thoughts?

Comment: the first one is properly the reason you get a blank page, the other 2 is becouse of the first one, i see if i can see whats happening on row 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is discused at this site: http://old.support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/5953/declaration-of-acf_taxonomy_field_walkerstart_el/p1

in short they fixed a bug in the addon:

wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/taxonomy.php row/line 419:

```
function start_el( &$output, $term, $depth, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
```

wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/taxonomy.php row/line 442:

```
function end_el( &$output, $term, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found that page too. I upgraded the plugin and it seemed to correct the issue. Thanks for your help!